# Copy in VIM, pasting to Word

Tags: vim

I am copying specific lines in VIM using, `92GV145Gy`, but I am then unable to paste into word. The correct lines are yanked. I have also tried copying the entire vim file and am still unable to paste. Is there a specific way to do this?

Comment: `set clipboard=unnamed` in your `.vimrc` as long as your `vim --version` was compiled with `+clipboard`.

Answer (score 1):

The yank (`y`) command only will yank to Vim's default register `"`. In order to copy to the system clipboard, you'll need to yank to either register `*` or `+` depending on what OS you are running. So for your example, it would be `92GV145G"*y` or `92GV145G"+y`.

And if that doesn't work, you'll need to verify whether the Vim you are using had clipboard capability compiled into it, or if you're using neovim, if a clipboard provider is properly configured (which you can check with `:checkhealth`).

Also view: [Difference between “* and ”+ registers in +clipboard VIM?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22205/difference-between-and-registers-in-clipboard-vim/)

Comment: When should you use ```*``` vs ```+```?